# Communication between custom web page using a Allen Bradley 1768-EWEB Module

Tags: xml, server, plc

Experts,

Has anyone been successful in setting up a 1768-EWEB Module by Allen Bradley?. The scope of my problem is the communication between a web page, that will update the xml files saved under a directory inside the EWEB Module; which then will be read by the module and transmitted back to the PLC.

The manual is very specific that the only way to accomplish this, is by using "Web Page Forms and POST Handlers".

The code sample provided in the manual is the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>
        Data View Javascript Demo Page
      </title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlDoc;
    var xmlhttp;
    var DATAVIEW_URI = "/user/system/dataviews/Sample.xml";
    var DATAVIEW_NAMESPACE = "http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/";
    var DATATYPES_NAMESPACE = "http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_types/1.0/";
    var ARR_ACTIVEX = ["MSXML4.DOMDocument", "MSXML3.DOMDocument", "MSXML2.DOMDocument", "MSXML.DOMDocument",
    "Microsoft.XmlDom"];
    var STR_ACTIVEX = "";
    var isIE = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1;
    if (isIE) {
    var bFound = false;
    for (var i=0; i < ARR_ACTIVEX.length && !bFound; i++) {
    try {
    var objXML = new ActiveXObject(ARR_ACTIVEX[i]);
    STR_ACTIVEX = ARR_ACTIVEX[i];
    bFound = true
    } catch (objException) {}
    }
    if (!bFound) {
    /* No DOM found, so throw a message and go back */
    alert("Creating/editing a data view requires Internet Explorer 5.5 or greater with XML support. Please
    upgrade your browser or load the appropriate patches to support XML.");
    history.go(-1);
    }
    } else {
    /* Not IE, so throw a message and go back */
    alert("Creating/editing a data view requires Internet Explorer 5.5 or greater with XML support. Please
    upgrade your browser or load the appropriate patches to support XML.");
    history.go(-1);
    }
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject(STR_ACTIVEX)
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
    if (STR_ACTIVEX.indexOf(".DOMDocument") != -1) {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(STR_ACTIVEX.substring(0, STR_ACTIVEX.indexOf(".DOMDocument")) +
    ".XMLHTTP");
    } else {
    alert("Creating/editing a data view requires Internet Explorer 5.5 or greater with XML support. Please
    upgrade your browser or load the appropriate patches to support XML.");
    history.go(-1);
    }
    function refresh_value() {
    xmlDoc.load(DATAVIEW_URI);
    xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:dv='" + DATAVIEW_NAMESPACE + "'");
    document.getElementById("tagvalue").value =
    xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/dv:view/dv:tag[@name='TEST']/dv:value").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    function update_value() {
    xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/dv:view/dv:tag[@name='TEST']/dv:value").childNodes[0].nodeValue =
    document.getElementById("tagvalue").value;
    xmlhttp.Open("POST", DATAVIEW_URI, false);
    xmlhttp.Send(xmlDoc);
    refresh_value();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="refresh_value();">
    TEST value is <input type="text" name="tagvalue" id="tagvalue" /><br/>
    <input type="button" onClick="refresh_value();" value="Refresh"/><input type="button"
    onClick="update_value();" value="Update"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I test the code above (on IE 10), it does not work. The field form is blank. According to the manual, it should show 125. (Steps like creating the xml in the wizard has been already done).

Has anyone had the chance to work with this web module? This device is from year 2004-2006 and it only handles .asp as server-side language.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When I copy that into a text file test.html and debug in IE10 it throws an error that it cannot find the refresh_value() function. I would be suspect of the validity of the script. Also I suggest you tag this question with html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying that raw code into a test.html file and opening in IE10 as you say it doesn't work. I found that there are newline characters in the script that cause it to become invalid - particularly the string literals in the `alert(" ")`'s. I have found in the past that copying from manuals, pdfs and help files can include unwanted characters so double check those with a good code editor. It also helps to set your indenting so you can easily see what is happening in the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Data View Javascript Demo Page
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlDoc;
    var xmlhttp;
    var DATAVIEW_URI = "/user/system/dataviews/Sample.xml";
    var DATAVIEW_NAMESPACE = "http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_views/1.0/";
    var DATATYPES_NAMESPACE = "http://www.rockwellautomation.com/technologies/data_access/data_types/1.0/";
    var ARR_ACTIVEX = ["MSXML4.DOMDocument", "MSXML3.DOMDocument", "MSXML2.DOMDocument", "MSXML.DOMDocument", "Microsoft.XmlDom"];
    var STR_ACTIVEX = "";
    var isIE = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1;
    if (isIE) {
        var bFound = false;
        for (var i=0; i < ARR_ACTIVEX.length && !bFound; i++) {
            try {
                var objXML = new ActiveXObject(ARR_ACTIVEX[i]);
                STR_ACTIVEX = ARR_ACTIVEX[i];
                bFound = true
            } catch (objException) {}
        }
        if (!bFound) {
            /* No DOM found, so throw a message and go back */
            alert("Creating/editing a data view requires Internet Explorer 5.5 or greater with XML support. Please upgrade your browser or load the appropriate patches to support XML.");
            history.go(-1);
        }
    } else {
        /* Not IE, so throw a message and go back */
        alert("Creating/editing a data view requires Internet Explorer 5.5 or greater with XML support. Please upgrade your browser or load the appropriate patches to support XML.");
        history.go(-1);
    }
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject(STR_ACTIVEX)
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
    if (STR_ACTIVEX.indexOf(".DOMDocument") != -1) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(STR_ACTIVEX.substring(0, STR_ACTIVEX.indexOf(".DOMDocument")) + ".XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        alert("Creating/editing a data view requires Internet Explorer 5.5 or greater with XML support. Please upgrade your browser or load the appropriate patches to support XML.");
        history.go(-1);
    }
    function refresh_value() {
        xmlDoc.load(DATAVIEW_URI);
        xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:dv='" + DATAVIEW_NAMESPACE + "'");
        document.getElementById("tagvalue").value =
        xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/dv:view/dv:tag[@name='TEST']/dv:value").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    function update_value() {
        xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/dv:view/dv:tag[@name='TEST']/dv:value").childNodes[0].nodeValue =
        document.getElementById("tagvalue").value;
        xmlhttp.Open("POST", DATAVIEW_URI, false);
        xmlhttp.Send(xmlDoc);
        refresh_value();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="refresh_value();">
    TEST value is <input type="text" name="tagvalue" id="tagvalue" /><br/>
    <input type="button" onClick="refresh_value();" value="Refresh"/>
    <input type="button" onClick="update_value();" value="Update"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now your next hurdle will be getting a browser to run that code because the ActiveX may not be supported in IE10. That is a different question though...

Comment: Strongbutgood - You are right! There was a line break. Now the code runs. Many people trying to have this sample code from the manual are not aware of this and it leads to believe the XML approach is not viable.